# Возврат auto значения шаблона

Tags: c++

Как вернуть неизвестный заранее тип переменной шаблона при помощи ключевого слова `auto` ?

```
error C2672: 'GetValue': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: '_Out GetValue(_In &)': could not deduce template argument for '_Out'
note: see declaration of 'GetValue'
error C2672: 'GetValue': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: '_Out GetValue(_In &)': could not deduce template argument for '_Out'
note: see declaration of 'GetValue'
```

Код:

```
const unsigned short V_INT = 0;
const unsigned short V_DOUBLE = 1;

typedef unsigned short TYPE;
struct ESAMPLE
{
    union
    {
        TYPE type;
        union
        {
            int _INT;
            double _DOUBLE;
        };
    };
};

template<typename _Out, typename _In>
inline _Out GetValue(_In& v)
{
    switch (v.type)
    {
    case V_INT:
        return v._INT;
    case V_DOUBLE:
        return v._DOUBLE;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ESAMPLE e;
    e.type = V_INT;
    e._INT = -128;
    auto x = GetValue(e); // must return 'int'

    ESAMPLE e2;
    e.type = V_DOUBLE;
    e._DOUBLE = 128;
    auto x2 = GetValue(e2); // must return 'double'
}
```

Comment: Никакого отношения к `auto` ошибки в вашем коде не имеют. При таком объявлении шаблона `GetValue` тип `_Out` дедуцирован быть не может, как вам ясно сказал компилятор. Никакого `auto` там и близко нет. Вот и все. В любом случае: так не бывает. Функция не может возвращать разные типы в зависимости от параметра времени выполнения, и никакие шаблоны или `auto` тут вам никак не помогут.

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь,  но структура ESAMPLE выглядит весьма странно.   Как понимаю,  Вы хотели хранить в ней данные и информацию об их типе. Но так,  мне кажется,  не получится при Вашем варианте её объявления.  Не нужно тип данных и данные упаковывать в union.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону std::variant и может шаблона visitor